# How to get path parameters from URL in React Redux-Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I want to get path parameters from URL but when I use `useParams()` it doesn't work in Redux-Toolkit.

Example of the code:

```js
export const getArticleTitle = createAsyncThunk<
  ArticleData[],
  void,
  { rejectValue: AxiosError }
>("article/fetchAllArticle", async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    let { title } = useParams();
    const newsid = title!.split("-").join(" ");
    const response = await artikelService.getArtikelIni(newsid);
    return response as ArticleData[];
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
      return rejectWithValue(error);
    }
    throw error;
  }
});
```

I need a way to get path parameter from URLs in a way that is suitable for use in the Redux-Toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using React Router's `useParams` within your redux actions or reducers because actions and reducers are expected to be pure functions. In your case, you can pass your route parameter as a payload when dispatching your action.

```
export const getArticleTitle = createAsyncThunk<ArticleData[], void, { 
    rejectValue: AxiosError }>("article/fetchAllArticle", 
       async (title, { rejectWithValue }) => {
         try {
           const newsid = title!.split("-").join(" ");
           const response = await artikelService.getArtikelIni(newsid);
           return response as ArticleData[];
         } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
             return rejectWithValue(error);
         }
           throw error;
      }
});
```

And you can dispatch in your component like this;

```
    const MyComponent = () => {
      const { title } = useParams();

      useEffect(() => {
         dispatch(getArticleTitle(title))
      }, [dispatch, title])
    }
```

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

Use JS native search params instaed of react hook

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const product = urlParams.get('product')
```

Answer (score 0):

React hooks, e.g. the `useParams` hook, can only be called from React functions and custom React hooks. They can't be used in nested functions like an action creator.

The `getArticleTitle` action should only concern itself with getting an article by a specific title id. In other words, you should de-couple it from trying to read values from external resources. Pass in the value you would like to use for the query.

```js
export const getArticleTitle = createAsyncThunk<
  ArticleData[],
  void,
  { rejectValue: AxiosError }
>(
  "article/fetchAllArticle",
  async (newsId, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await artikelService.getArtikelIni(newsId);
      return response as ArticleData[];
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        return rejectWithValue(error);
      }
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

In the UI use the `useParams` hook and compute the `newsId` value you need for the query.

```js
const { title } = useParams();
const newsId = title!.split("-").join(" ");

...

dispatch(getArticleTitle(newsId));

...
```